# Pin It hover on single image?

Tags: pinterest

do you know if its possible to have the pint it mouse over on a single image? right now I use this:

```
<!-- Please call pinit.js only once per page -->
<script type="text/javascript" async  data-pin-hover="true"
src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

But that is placing a pint it on every image on that page, I just have 3 or 4 images that needs the hover action, not all the whole images in that page, any idea guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the pinterest documentation, I think by default it wants to put a pinit button on everything.  So to exclude images, you have to add the exclude specifically on every image for which you do not want the image to appear:

`data-pin-no-hover="true"`

https://developers.pinterest.com/on_hover_pin_it_buttons/

Comment: it'd be nice to be able to add the button to 1 or 2 images rather than remove it from 50 others.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery I just did the following since I set the following pinterest attribute on all the images I wanted the save button to show up on...

```
         //remove Pinterest save button for all images
         $("img").attr("data-pin-no-hover", true);
         //add it back to images for which I've defined the pinterest image
         $("img[data-pin-media]").removeAttr("data-pin-no-hover");
```